# BigQuery - Table joins using the Storage Read API

Tags: join, google-bigquery

Is there a way to do a join between two tables using the Storage Read API similar to how is done using SQL with the `JOIN` statement?

I am working on an application with an increasing number of RPS so I'd like to avoid using SQL in order to save costs and reduce latency.

Comment: Is your question about how to join two tables programmatically using BigQuery storage API?

Comment: @kiranmathew yes

Comment: Hi @Nicolas Arias, I have provided an answer, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, you can consider the below example:

```
import pandas
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage import BigQueryReadClient
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage import types
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage

projectBilling = 'my-project'
project_id = "my-project"
parent = "projects/{}".format(projectBilling)
Storageclient = bigquery_storage.BigQueryReadClient()

def read_table(dataset_id,table_id):
    dataset_id = dataset_id
    table_id = table_id
    table = f"projects/{project_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/tables/{table_id}"
    read_options = types.ReadSession.TableReadOptions()
    requestedSession = types.ReadSession(table=table,data_format=types.DataFormat.ARROW,read_options=read_options,)
    readSession = Storageclient.create_read_session(parent=parent,read_session=requestedSession,max_stream_count=1,)
    stream = readSession.streams[0]
    reader = Storageclient.read_rows(stream.name)
    Data_frame = []
    for messages in reader.rows().pages:
        Data_frame.append(messages.to_dataframe())
    dataframe = pandas.concat(Data_frame)
    return dataframe


df1=read_table("zz","dpr")
print("\n Table1 \n")
print(df1)
df2=read_table("zz","emp")
print("\n Table2 \n")
print(df2)
print("\n  Joined Table \n")
Joined_table=pandas.merge(df1,df2,left_on='name',right_on='edp',how="inner")
print(Joined_table)
```

Result:

[image]

In the above example I am using the python pandas module to join two tables.To know more you can follow this [link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-types-of-joins-in-pandas/) and [link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-5-google-cloud-bigquery-apis-aafdf4ef0181).

Comment: With BigQuery Storage API you don't have a SELECT statement. This example still uses the standard query mechanism, and not the Storage API itself.

Comment: Hi @Pentium10,thanks for your comment I updated my answer.